# Dúvida usando a API Proxy do JavaScript

Tags: javascript, proxy

Fiz este código para estudar o Proxy do JavaScript. Ele funciona detectando a alteração da propriedade do objeto porém quando chamo a propriedade no console.log ele não aparece alterada

JS

```
var f = {nome: "Fulano"}

f = new Proxy (f, {
  set: (target, prop) => {
        if (prop === "nome") {
        alert('Nome alterado')
    }
  }
})

$('#edita').click(() => {
    f.nome = $('input').val()
  console.log(f.nome)
})
```

HTML

```
<input type="text">
<button id="edita">EDITAR NOME</button>
```

Após alterar o nome no evento click do botão o console.log ainda exibe Fulano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O objeto `Proxy` tem um alto grau de flexibilidade, não serve somente para observar mudanças efetuas encima de um objeto, e justamente por esse motivo que quando você escreve um comportamento como `set`, `get`, `has`, você precisa o sobreescrever por inteiro. Foi isso que faltou no seu `set`, faltou delegar o comportamento de atribuição para o `target`.

```
var f = {nome: "Fulano"}

f = new Proxy (f, {
  set(target, prop, value) {
    if (prop === "nome") {
      alert('Nome alterado')
    }

    target[prop] = value;
  }
})
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado.