# Proxy Object em javascript

Tags: javascript

Deparei-me com um tipo de objecto chamado proxy em javascript qual é a sua real utilidade?

E o que seriam as traps/armadilhas?

Comment: Relacionado: [Dúvida usando a API Proxy do JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/161249/d%C3%BAvida-usando-a-api-proxy-do-javascript)

Comment: recomendo a leitura: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `Proxy` vem solucionar uma necessidade antiga, a de poder interceptar e redirecionar código dependente de lógica. Meio abstrato talvez, mas (e apesar disto ser possível com métodos elaborados) o `Proxy` permite escutar mudanças num objeto e reagir sem que quem solicitou um valor seja afetado.

Mais concreto: usando `Proxy` podemos ter um objeto virtual, sem propriedades e através do Proxy gerir o que é retornado de cada pedido (get) a esse objeto.

Exemplo:

```js
const objetoVazio = {bar: ''};
let somaDeSetters = 0;
const objetoVirtual = new Proxy(objetoVazio, {
  get: function(objeto, chave) {
    if (!(chave in objeto)) {
      console.log('Tentou aceder a um valor que não existe!');
      return null;
    }

    return objeto[chave];
  },
  set: function(objeto, chave, valor) {
    if (!(chave in objeto)) {
      console.log('Tentou settar a um valor que não existe!');
      return null;
    } else {
      console.log(`A chave ${chave} já foi setada ${(somaDeSetters++)} vezes`);
      objeto[chave] = valor;
    }
  }
});
objetoVirtual.foo = 200;
objetoVirtual.bar = 'baz';
objetoVirtual.bar = 'buzz!';

var x = objetoVirtual.foo;
var y = objetoVirtual.bar;
console.log(x, y); // null, buz
```

Neste exemplo em cima fazemos verificação antes do get e set se o objeto tem a propriedade/chave pedida. [Sugeri uma função semelhante na biblioteca Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1120). Outra possibilidade seria fazer validação de Tipo, por exemplo em forms. Caso o valor setado não seja do mesmo Tipo (numero, string, etc) que a chave permite então podemos retornar um erro ou um aviso e impedir sobre-escrever o valor.

Proxy abre inúmeras possibilidades para controlar objetos, arrays, etc, permitindo ter controlo total sobre o objeto inicial **que nunca é exposto** a quem o quer modificar.

Comment: Realmente interessante pensar em utilizar os proxies como auxiliar de validação de formulários.